# Multiple assignments var a = b = b || {} in javascript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Reading leaflet.js 's code, I came across a method with this line which I don't fully understand:

```
var events = this._leaflet_events = this._leaflet_events || {};
```

which can be simplified as

```
var a = b = b || {};
```

From what I understand this instruction is a multiple left-handed assignment that is right associative which means that first, JavaScript will run

```
b = b || {} //if b exists, returns b, else return an empty object
```

, then

```
a = b // returns the output of the preceding instruction
```

Which does not make sense to me. Why not write instead:

```
a = b || {};
```

Full context:

```
addEventListener: function( /*string*/ type, /*function */ fn, /*(optional) object*/ context){
    var events = this._leaflet_events = this._leaflet_events || {};
        events[type] = events[type] || {};
        events[type].push({
        action: fn,
        context: context || this
        });
    return this;
}
```

I suspect a reference trick since I don't see how `this._leaflet_events` gets modified by the method otherwise.

---

Thinking about it, writing `var a = b = b || {}` is actually be a trick to assign `var a` a reference to `b`, no matter whether `b` is defined or not. Modifying `a` now modifies `b`.

Back to Leaflet. With

```
    var events = this._leaflet_events = this._leaflet_events || {};
```

`this._leaflet_events` either exists or is initialized to `{}`.
`events` is assigned `this._leaflet_events` by reference. The reference's value might be `{}` but it is still `this._leaflet_events` that is being modified when modifying `events`.

On the contrary, writing

```
    var events = this._leaflet_events || {};
```

would be a mistake , since if `this._leaflet_events` is not defined, `events` will now point to a newly created object whose value will be `{}`. Modifying `events` will change the new object but it won't change `this._leaflet_events`'s value.

Same appearent values, different references. Here is the thing.

Comment: FYI, `this._leaflet_events` is different than `this._leaflet.events`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shorter expression will not set anything as b's value

```
a = b = b || {}; //set b's b value to {} if b is uncdefined, then set a's value to b

a = b || {}; //set a's value to b, or {} if b is undefined
```

the first statement is in fact equivalent to

```
b = b || {};
a = b;
```

Answer (score 10):

The statement `var a = b = b || {};` does *two* things:

- It initializes b to `{}` if it was undefined.
- It sets a to the same as b.

The expression `a = b || {};` does not not modify b so it is not equivalent.

Comment: You didn't spot the different in the two variable names - see my answer.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I think it's just a typo in the question. Check the original source code: https://github.com/cvisto/Leaflet/blob/has_clearEventListeners/src/core/Events.js#L23